# PostgresException: 42883: operator does not exist: @ character varying

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, forms, razor

im trying to make a reservation page in razor pages c#. If i make a reservation it will also appear on the page for the user. I made a button next to every reservation so you can delete the reservation. The reservation shows on the page only the date and the location. When I try to delete it from the page i get this error: PostgresException: 42883: operator does not exist: @ character varying
And have no idea why.
Here is the c# side:

```cs
public void OnPostRemove(ReservationModel reservation)
{
    DateTime convdayid = Convert.ToDateTime(reservation.Dayid);
    DeleteReservation(convdayid, reservation.Locationid);
}

public void DeleteReservation(DateTime convdayid, string Locationid)
{
    
    var cs = Database.Database.Connector();
    using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
    con.Open();

    var sql = "DELETE FROM reservation WHERE locationid = @Locationid AND dayid = @convdayid;";
    using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("locationnid", Locationid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dayid", convdayid);
    cmd.Prepare();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

And this is the html side if necessary

```
@foreach(var reservations in @Model.ShowReservation())
{
    <form method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <tr>
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="/Images/Reservation.png"/>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => reservations.Dayid)
                        <input type="hidden" name="Dayid" value="@Html.DisplayFor(m => reservations.Dayid)"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => reservations.Locationid)
                        <input type="hidden" name="Locationid" value="@Html.DisplayFor(m => reservations.Locationid)"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <button type="submit" value="Submit" asp-page-handler="Remove" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <hr>
}
<hr>
```

---

**Edit**:

The error got solved, but for some reason the specific row doesnt get deleted from the database. Nothing happens. This is what I changed about my code.

```
public void OnPostRemove(ReservationModel reservation)
        {
            DateTime convdayid = Convert.ToDateTime(reservation.Dayid);
            DeleteReservation(convdayid, reservation.Locationid);
        }

        public void DeleteReservation(DateTime convdayid, string Locationid)
        {
            
            var cs = Database.Database.Connector();
            using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();

            var sql = "DELETE FROM reservation WHERE locationid = @locationid AND dayid = @dayid;";
            using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("locationid", Locationid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dayid", convdayid);
            cmd.Prepare();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

Comment: Note you have `@Locationid` but `locationnid` (different case), and `@convdayid` but `dayid` (entirely different words)

Comment: so you mean they have to be exactly the same? so locationid = @locationid

Comment: I wasn't clear -- the name you pass to `Parameters.AddWithValue` needs to be the same as the placeholder name you use in `sql` (the thing prefixed with `@`). So if you use `WHERE locationid = @HelloMum`, you need to use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HelloMum", ....)`

Comment: Thank you! It removed the error :) but for some reason the row doesnt get removed from the database. Have any idea?

Comment: Could you update your question to contain the code you're currently running? Otherwise I have to guess at what you've done.

Comment: Yes, i just updated it!

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure that the values for `Locationid` and `convayid` are correct? What data type is `dayid` in your schema: is it `timestamp without time zone` or a `date`?

Comment: locationid is varchar, and column dayid is of type date. But in c# i made a reservationmodel, and made Locationid a string and Dayid also a string, so that it can be shown on the page. And if i want to put Dayid in database or delete, i simply convert it to DateTime, thats why i used the convdayid variable

Comment: The next is probably to look at the query that Npgsql is sending to your database, see if anything there looks incorrect

Answer (score -2):

Its trying to parse the '@' as '=@'

```
DELETE FROM reservation WHERE locationid = @Locationid AND dayid = @convdayid;
```

Is literally being passed to the Db. You need to build that string so @LocationID and @convdaid are populated accordingly. Something like:

```
DELETE FROM reservation WHERE locationid = 34 AND dayid = 55;
```

Comment: You start off correct, but the solution is to use the parameters system correctly, not ignore it entirely. Please don't encourage things which inevitably lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities

Comment: This did also remove the error, i just passed the parameters from the function to this query without the @.  But when i click on one button all the rows get deleted, instead i need only one specific row that should be deleted. As shown in html, maybe theres something wrong with my html?

Comment: @anonD Please do not construct SQL queries by inserting raw values into your SQL statements. You make yourself vulnerable to SQL injection, where an attacker can execute arbitrary SQL statements (and potentially do things like read or modify your database, or delete everything)

Comment: @canton7 Really this should be calling a Db function that performs this task. Still not sure what 'parameters system' you are referring to ?

Comment: @VynlJunkie For example, `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/commands-and-parameters

Comment: @canton7 Not C guy, but thanks for heads up.